# Java split method to split after closing bracket

Tags: java, regex, split

Given the following sample input:

```
rgb(97, 0, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box
```

I'm trying to split this string right after the closing bracket with the following regex:

```
string.split("\\)\\s")[0]
```

Problem is that this approach is chopping off the bracket:

```
rgb(97, 0, 255
```

How can I get the following output?

```
rgb(97, 0, 255)
```

How do I split without chopping off the closing bracket?

Comment: @Jens zero-width matches will not be removed. Or rather, they would but that removes the empty string. You can still split based on some character and still keep it.

Comment: Why are you using `split` at all?  Why not just `s.substring(0, s.indexOf(")") + 1)`?  Note:  parsing CSS is a lot more complicated than just splitting a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need a Positive Lookbehind, which will look for what's before your match, yet without matching it:

```
(?<=\))\s
```

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/aMjovv/1).